# $_SESSION keeps old value

Tags: php, mysql

i am coding PHP and I have a problem with my $_SESSION variable. it should get a new value, but it keeps his old value insteed of the new one.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/config.inc.php");
require_once("inc/functions.inc.php");
include("templates/header.inc.php");// simple the header, nothing important ;)

?>

<?php
$statement = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM fragen");
$result = $statement->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo '<a class="kein" href="forum_forum.php"><div class="forum"><div class="forum_Titel">' ,"Titel:  ".$row['fragen_title'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Subt  itel">', "Subtitel:  " .$row['fragen_subtitle'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Content">',"Text:  ".$row['fragen_content'].'</div>',
        "br><br>",'<div>'.$row['fragen_id'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Upload-date">',"Upload-Datum:  ".$row['fragen_date'].'</div>',
        '</div></a>',
        $chosen_one = $row['fragen_id'];    //the variable $chosen_one should get the value of the id   
        $_SESSION['chosen_one'] = $chosen_one; // and here I want to make this variable global for the next site.
}
?>
<?php 
include("templates/footer.inc.php");
?>
```

the output (new site) should be the content where fragen_id is the same like my $_SESSION['chosen_one'] but it want work

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/config.inc.php");
require_once("inc/functions.inc.php");
include("templates/header.inc.php");
$chosen_one = $_SESSION['chosen_one'];
echo $chosen_one;
?>

<?php
$statement = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM fragen WHERE fragen_id =$chosen_one");
$result = $statement->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo '<div class="forum"><div class="forum_Titel">' ,"Titel:  ".$row['fragen_title'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Subitel">', "Subtitel:  " .$row['fragen_subtitle'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Content">',"Text:  ".$row['fragen_content'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Bild"><img class="pic" alt="Ein Bild" title="Eine Pflanzen" src="'.$row['fragen_picture'].'">',
        "<br><br>","Bildlink:  ".$row['fragen_picture'].'</div>',
        "<br><br>",'<div class="forum_Upload-date">',"Upload-Datum:  ".$row['fragen_date'].'</div>',
        '</div>';

}
?>
<?php 
include("templates/footer.inc.php");
?>
```

here are my functions:

```
<?php
/**
 * A complete login script with registration and members area.
 *
 * @author: Nils Reimers / http://www.php-einfach.de/experte/php-codebeispiele/loginscript/
 * @license: GNU GPLv3
 */
include_once("password.inc.php");

/**
 * Checks that the user is logged in. 
 * @return Returns the row of the logged in user
 */
function check_user() {
    global $pdo;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) && isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) && isset($_COOKIE['securitytoken'])) {
        $identifier = $_COOKIE['identifier'];
        $securitytoken = $_COOKIE['securitytoken'];

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM securitytokens WHERE identifier = ?");
        $result = $statement->execute(array($identifier));
        $securitytoken_row = $statement->fetch();

        if(sha1($securitytoken) !== $securitytoken_row['securitytoken']) {
            //Vermutlich wurde der Security Token gestohlen
            //Hier ggf. eine Warnung o.ä. anzeigen

        } else { //Token war korrekt
            //Setze neuen Token
            $neuer_securitytoken = random_string();
            $insert = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE securitytokens SET securitytoken = :securitytoken WHERE identifier = :identifier");
            $insert->execute(array('securitytoken' => sha1($neuer_securitytoken), 'identifier' => $identifier));
            setcookie("identifier",$identifier,time()+(3600*24*365)); //1 Jahr Gültigkeit
            setcookie("securitytoken",$neuer_securitytoken,time()+(3600*24*365)); //1 Jahr Gültigkeit

            //Logge den Benutzer ein
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $securitytoken_row['user_id'];
        }
    }


    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        die('Bitte zuerst <a href="login.php">einloggen</a>');
    }


    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $result = $statement->execute(array('id' => $_SESSION['userid']));
    $user = $statement->fetch();
    return $user;


}

/*
Returns true when the user is checked in, else false
*/
function is_checked_in() {
    return isset($_SESSION['userid']);
}

/**
 * Returns a random string
 */
function random_string() {
    if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes); 
    } else if(function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes); 
    } else {
        //Replace your_secret_string with a string of your choice (>12 characters)
        $str = md5(uniqid('your_secret_string', true));
    }   
    return $str;
}

/**
 * Returns the URL to the site without the script name
 */
function getSiteURL() {
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    return $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/';
}

/**
 * Outputs an error message and stops the further exectution of the script.
 */
function error($error_msg) {
    include("templates/header.inc.php");
    include("templates/error.inc.php");
    include("templates/footer.inc.php");
    exit();
}
```

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: `$_SESSION['chosen_one']` always store the last `$row['fragen_id']` value. Are you aware of that, right?

Comment: Are those first 3 blocks of `<?php .. ?>` all in the same script file?

Comment: How many `$row['fragen_id']` did you want to store in the session? Just the last one or all of then returned in that loop

Comment: Which of these lines stores something into the session? Which exact key are you talking about that does not change? Have you checked whether the code runs into the branches that change something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your style.
what happens if $_SESSION['chosen_one'] == NULL ?

you are getting all records with

```
$statement = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM fragen");
```

then in your while loop, you are setting the row value of the current element to a session variable

```
$chosen_one = $row['fragen_id'];    //the variable $chosen_one should get the value of the id   
    $_SESSION['chosen_one'] = $chosen_one; // and here I want to make this variable global for the next site.
```

**the result is, you will always have the last item of the resultset in your session variable**

the question here is how do you get the chosenid ?

please mark as answer if it helped

Comment: do you know how i could fix this?

Comment: well the question is what are you trying to archive?

usually you build your query and filter for data  you want to receive instead of getting all records

$statement = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT * FROM fragen WHERE fragen_id=$myid"); // quick code, you should check for sql injections

now you need to get $myid from somewhere in your code, maybe you have a frontend where you can select something, then you can pass the id from there

if you expect only one row (like if you filter it by id) you can just fetch that row instead of using a loop.

Comment: i want to make kind of a forum inside a website, and if you press one one title, the hole content is opened in another page. So I have to achieve that I can link every title with the content of it...

Comment: well its hard to describe in short form, but you usually do a select on all boards and then inside your fetch loop, you render each forum with its id, so you build up links like boards.php?boardid=$id
and if you select it, you need to select all topics with the related board id and render all topics the same way..
Maybe you should checkout some tutorials to get the basic idea and then write your own one..
Didn't check this tutorial, but maybe it helps you to get the basic idea https://www.phpgang.com/create-a-simple-forum-in-php_158.html

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your logout page or at the top of this page before you start.

```
 $_SESSION['xxx'] = ''; //for each variable you want to unset.
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```